# Can your single status affect your employment/advancement?

Tags: company-culture, colleagues

I am a single male, 30. I have never been interested in pursuing relationships. I guess I am asexual as its never been something I have pursued with anyone. I am finishing up my last semester of grad school and now that I am going to be entering the workforce I am a little concerned about co-worker's reactions to me. My previous part-time job was online so I didn't have to worry about that.
In college that was never an issue as no one really cared. I got asked maybe once if I had a significant other.

I tried my best to be polite/courteous/helpful whenever possible with my peers and that seemed to help. I didn't get any nosy/prying questions into my personal life. I live with my mom, aunt and younger sibling - so when it came to family that's what I would talk about. Mom's got a lot of health issues so I guess most figured I was too busy or had not time. Also I practice Tibetan Buddhism and there are lay practitioners that will take the celibacy precept even if they dont ordain.

I guess my questions would be since it seems acceptable to ask about other's relationship status and how casually people with talk about their spouses/bf/gf...would I be seen as a "weirdo" or the topic of gossip? I plan to keep my approach of being polite and helpful - thats worked in school I dont know about the actual workplace. Also it seems that there is a lot 'after hours socializing/drinking' since I practice Buddhism I dont drink. Dont know if that will make me even more of an outcast?

I seem to be getting 2 VASTLY different responses: I have asked friends and they seem to be under the idea that "no one really cares about your personal life" and others (internet mainly) that make it seem like co-workers will make your life difficult and you will be seen as some 'weirdo' or 'outcast' for being a single male in 30's with no spouse/SO.

How bad is it really? Enough to get impact your career/advancement? Then there is the "*must be gay*" default a lot of people go to. Which I could care less about ...except I live in a state where sadly you **CAN** get fired for that.
At worst I figure I could say "single for religious reasons". At least that might be covered under employment discrimination protection. 
Oh and I am a terrible liar, so making up a story of gf/SO is not going to work.
Any input would be helpful.

Comment: You mention "state", so you're in the US? What field or type of company, government agency, NGO, are you looking at? One possible answer is "I'm focusing on my career right now."

Comment: Yes, in the Midwest. Healthcare field but administrative. I have thought about that response but over time how will that hold? I guess I wondering if that is really such a big deal for others. I know its uncommon, but would that really be as bad as to affect my employment/advancement?

Comment: Personally, the weirdest part for me is that you live with your mom, aunt, and sister at 30. If that's for her benefit and not yours, then you may want to mention that when you talk about your living situation.

Comment: Yes, my dad passed away and there was little left in savings- he was not very good at planning ahead. Then my mom's health complications got worse and she cant work. As the eldest all responsibility fell on me to take care of the family. Last year my aunt had a stroke and she is a widower with no kids in her late 60's had to move in. So yeah...there it is

Comment: @Kat It is perfectly normal in my place that we would stay with our family, but for your culture, yeah it is pretty weird.

Comment: @Revol729 details in the question implied the USA, where it is unusual. Much more so than not being in a relationship or not drinking, at any rate.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience as an engaged graduate entering the workforce, nobody knew I wasn't single for half a year before it came up in conversation.

Really nobody cares about anybody's personal life. You shouldn't worry about this at all. If it ever did come up you can just tell them exactly what you have said here. "I'm not interested in a relationship" that will be the last you will hear of it.

I will say that after about a year I was offered a promotion that involved moving overseas however I couldn't accept because my fiance has a career of her own that is very local to the area we are in.

It's no secret being independent/single is a huge leg up in the workforce starting out.

Also, I wouldn't worry about the after work culture of drinking etc. You can also go out and socialize if you want to and not drink. They are all adults no one is going to force you to do shots to fit in.

Comment: Agreed with all of this. Don't make a big deal about it and nobody else will either.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you don't need to mention all this in an interview, you're single with no kids and that's everything they need to know. I even consider that irrelevant and I think it might even be illegal to ask in some countries or states. But if that's a legitimate question, the answer can be as short as previously stated and you probably won't be asked to ellaborate more than that on the matter. You also probably don't want to be working for a company that would be more inquisitive than that on personal matters during an application process.
From an employment perspective, I think this is at worst considered a "neutral" status, if not a slight advantage as some might consider you'll be even more available than people with kids.

Now for the advancement part, it will really depend on companies you work for and the people deciding. Employment world is most of the time not a fair place, and people might judge you on non-professional criteria. Sure you could do your best to keep it strictly professional and might succeed to do it - although this can be hard sometimes - but even then people might penalize you for not socializing. My advice, for what it's worth, would be to be careful at first, get to know the people better and show them how professional you are, and then you'll see how comfortable you are opening more and more on personnal matters if you want at all. if you never feel comfortable or are negatively judged by others on your place of work because of who you are, it is probably better to just move on to another place where you will be appreciated and respected exactly for that...